# Unable to set a date using grey_setDate

Tags: ios, swift

I tried the reference of functionalTests from the sample project, which is below:

```
- (void)testDateOnlyPicker {
  NSString *dateString = @"1986/12/26";
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY/MM/dd";
  NSDate *desiredDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

  [[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_text(@"Date")] performAction:grey_tap()];

  [[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"DatePickerId")]
      performAction:[GREYActions actionForSetDate:desiredDate]];

  [[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"DatePickerId")]
      assertWithMatcher:grey_datePickerValue(desiredDate)];

  [[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"DateLabelId")]
      assertWithMatcher:grey_text(dateString)];
}
```

But since I am using Swift, I translated the code.

```
func testDateOnlyPicker() {
    var dateString = "1986/12/26"
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd"
    var desiredDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    EarlGrey.selectElementWithMatcher(grey_text("Date")).performAction(grey_tap())
    EarlGrey.selectElementWithMatcher(grey_accessibilityID("DatePickerId")).assertWithMatcher(grey_datePickerValue(desiredDate))
}
```

But my date format is .MediumStyle - Nov 2, 2016. Somehow desiredDate always ends up showing the current date and time in the full format with date and time.

Is this the correct approach ->

```
var dateString = "Nov 3, 2016"
var desiredDate = NSDate()
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MMM d,yyyy", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
desiredDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
```

Comment: This isn't specific to EarlGrey, it's more about how we format NSDates. It's probably better if you add ios tag to it.

Comment: Oh yeah sure. My bad. I accidentally tagged.